# Why Gmail sent has an unknown Yahoo account accompanying it?

Tags: gmail

Lately whenever I send a Gmail to others, an unknown Yahoo email address (in my name) also accompanies my Gmail, such that my friends receive at their end this Yahoo email address. Thus when they send a "reply" message, it is sent to this Yahoo address too.

I am unable to de-activate this Yahoo account as I cannot answer the two so-called "security answers they require eg what is the nickname of your eldest child".

Can you help?

Comment: Have you verified ALL google account settings.  If you did not create the yahoo account then somebody has compromised your Google account.

Answer (score 2):

Check your "Account Settings" in your gmail. Under the "Accounts" label, you have the option to "Send mail as:" and you can add other email accounts. This is probably where your problem lies.